# Error while sending POST request with data

Tags: python, python-requests, registration

I tried to create program which will create account on this site: https://www.kostkuj.cz/register
My main problem is that i dont really know how it works, so i re-builded one project to my requirements.

I also tried sending requests with login data as parsed text:

```
    email: "email@gmail.com"
    plainPassword: {first: "pass1", second: "pass1"}
    first: "pass1"
    second: "pass1"
    username: "username3"
```

But i dont know what i am doing wrong.

This is my whole code:

```
import requests


headers = {
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36 OPR/63.0.3368.71'
}

register_data = {
    {"username":"username3","email":"email@gmail.com","plainPassword":{"first":"pass1","second":"pass1"}}
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://api.kostkuj.cz/register'
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    r = s.post(url, data=register_data, headers=headers)
    print(r.content)
```

I am getting error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\jiris\Desktop\spamkostkuj.py", line 9, in <module>
   {"username":"username3","email":"email@gmail.com","plainPassword":{"first":"pass1","second":"pass1"}}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing `headers` needs ro in pair i.e. key value pair. In your case somthing like:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36 OPR/63.0.3368.71'
}
```

Secondly, your are sending data as dict of dict which is incorrect, instead send a `dict`, like:

```
register_data = {"username":"username3","email":"email@gmail.com","plainPassword":{"first":"pass1","second":"pass1"}}
```

Try this. Hopefully is should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
r = s.post(url, json=register_data, headers=headers)
```